Require string type to be return of a specific function
I want to have a type which looks like:
type MyProps = {
  context: string;
  // other props
}

Except I want the context to have been generated from a specific function / or at least have a specific type (though it's really a string). For example:
function getContext(props: ContextProps) {
 const { a, b, c } = props;

 return `${a} [ ${b} / ${c} ]`;
}

const myProps = {
  context: getContext({ a: "test", b: "ABC", c: "123" }),
};

But setting context to any string should fail:
const myProps = {
  context: "some other string",
};

I've tried this, but it allows a plain string to be set to context:
function getContext(props: ContextProps) {
 const { a, b, c } = props;

 return `${a} [ ${b} / ${c} ]` as ContextString;
}

type ContextString = string;

// or 

interface ContextString extends String { }

Is it possible to enforce this?

• What's ContextProps?  Please [edit] for the code to be a [mre] we can easily drop into our own IDEs and work on without first having to debug our way to the starting line. • Maybe you're looking for template literal types as shown in this playground link. Or maybe you're looking for branded primitives as shown in this playground link. Each has pros/cons; do you really care about enforcing a specific function? Or is it really the structure of the string?

So, you want nominal typing? You can use a branded type, which is about the closest you'll get in TS.

Sounds like you want to hold off on converting context to a string until you're done with it. Consider keeping as a type with three properties and overload its toString implementation.

How about the following:
type ContextString = `${string} [ ${string} / ${string} ]`;

